# Populating datagridview winforms .net 4.0

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having problems in loading a datagridview with 2 columns.
Form with a Datagridview and 1 button.

Department (text)
EmployeesByDpt( Combo)

I have a form with a datagridview and a Button (Load),when I press load the datagridview should be populated.
clicking on the Employee Combo should display all the employees that belong to a particular department.

I cannot seem to get it to work ,below is what I have done,

Any suggestions?At the moment nothing shows.**Thanks**

Code (for semplicity I have put all together)

```
     public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Repository repository;
    readonly DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colDepartment=new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    readonly DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colComboEmployeesByDpt = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        repository = new Repository();
        SetupDataGridView();
    }

    private void SetupDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += OnEditingControlShowing;
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += OnCellsValueChanged;
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        colDepartment.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        colDepartment.HeaderText = "Department Name";

        colComboEmployeesByDpt.DataPropertyName = "Employees";
        colComboEmployeesByDpt.HeaderText = "Employees";
        colComboEmployeesByDpt.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        //colComboEmployeesByDpt.DataSource = "FullName";


        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { colDepartment ,colComboEmployeesByDpt});
    }

    private void OnCellsValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OnEditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colDepartment.Index)
        {
            var control = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            if (control != null)
            {
                var bs = control.DataSource as BindingSource;
                if (bs != null)
                {
                    var comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
                    BindingList<Employee> employees = repository.GetEmployeeByDepartments(control.Text);
                    comboBox.DataSource = employees;
                    object employeeValue = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[colComboEmployeesByDpt.Index].Value;
                    if (employeeValue == DBNull.Value || employeeValue == null)

                    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != DBNull.Value && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
                    {
                        control.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BindingList<Department> departments = repository.GetDepartments();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = departments;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

    }
}

public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        Employees=new BindingList<Employee>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BindingList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    public BindingList<Department> GetDepartments()
    {
        var departments=new BindingList<Department>();
        departments.Add(new Department{Name = "Food"});
        departments.Add(new Department{Name = "Travel"});
        departments.Add(new Department{Name = "Beauty"});
        return departments;
    }
    public BindingList<Employee> GetEmployeeByDepartments(string name)
    {
        var employees = new BindingList<Employee>();
        switch (name)
        {
            case "Food":
                employees.Add(new Employee { FullName = "Jim Bloggs1" });
                employees.Add(new Employee { FullName = "Jim Bloggs2" });
                break;
            case "Travel":
                employees.Add(new Employee { FullName = "Marc Smith1" });
                employees.Add(new Employee { FullName = "Marc Smith2" });
                break;
            case "Beauty":
                  employees.Add(new Employee { FullName = "Mario XXX1" });
                  employees.Add(new Employee { FullName = "Mario XXX2" });
                break;

        }

        return employees;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply "Databind" does not seem to be a method on the datagridview.

Comment: There is no databind in the winforms one

Comment: @MethodMan it's a WinForms application, no need to have a DataBind method

Comment: sorry about that .. I was thinking it was web forms..

Answer (score 0):

Running your exact code, I ran into several problems.  The following explanation will show you what I did to fix each subsequent problem but with a warning: In the end I couldn't make a selection from the `ComboBox` without changing the binding method between the `DataGridView` and the `Departments` and dropping some provided code.

**ArgumentException thrown for each row**

Each row was throwing the exception: *"DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid."*  Changing the following line fixed this:

```
colComboEmployeesByDpt.DataPropertyName = "Employees";
```

to

```
colComboEmployeesByDpt.DataPropertyName = "Employee";
```

**Empty ComboBoxes**

Now you'll notice the ComboBoxes are all empty.  In the event handler `OnEditingControlShowing` the first `if statement` should check against `colComboEmployeesByDpt.Index` instead of `colDepartment.Index`.  But that's not enough because `if (bs != null)` will always be false.  Even fixing that check, `control.Text` is always empty.  Instead, try:

```
BindingList<Employee> employees = repository.GetEmployeeByDepartments(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[colDepartment.Index].Value.ToString());
```

With this, you'll see each `ComboBox` has the correct list of employee names.  However, the `ArgumentException` has returned.  Try as I might, I couldn't fix it this time.  (I suspect the `ComboBox` items lists were always empty, so the selected value was *"invalid"*.)

**Answer - Restructure**

To get it to work I made several core changes.  I completely dropped the following:

```
colComboEmployeesByDpt.DisplayMember = "FullName";

private void OnEditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

Then I added a public property to remember the Departments, manually bound each row's employees, and hooked-up `OnCellsValueChanged` to refresh the lists when the Department Name changed:

```
BindingList<Department> Departments { get; set; }

private void OnCellsValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == colDepartment.Index)
  {
    this.Departments[e.RowIndex].Employees = repository.GetEmployeeByDepartments(this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString());
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[colComboEmployeesByDpt.Index];
    cell.DataSource = this.Departments[e.RowIndex].Employees;
  }
}

private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); // Needed if the button can be clicked repeatedly.
  this.Departments = repository.GetDepartments();

  foreach (Department department in this.Departments)
  {
    department.Employees = repository.GetEmployeeByDepartments(department.Name);

    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone());

    DataGridViewTextBoxCell textCell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)(row.Cells[0]);
    textCell.Value = department.Name;

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells[1]);
    comboCell.DataSource = department.Employees;
    comboCell.DisplayMember = "FullName";

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
  }
}
```

This solution worked for me.  When I have free time I will continue to look into fixing your original solution from the point that stumped me.  Hope this helps for now.